# Why are eigenvalues real as well as complex?

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, math-software

I have this $3\times 3$ matrix 
\begin{bmatrix} 5&2&3\\1&3&0\\ 1&0&1\end{bmatrix}

Its characteristic polynomial is $x^3-9x^2+18x-4$

Using Wolfram alpha the eigenvalues of the above matrix are coming as

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%7B%7B5%2C2%2C3%7D%2C%7B1%2C3%2C0%7D%2C%7B1%2C0%2C1%7D%7D+eigenvalues

which are real numbers but when I am solving the characteristic polynomial given above I am getting it as complex numbers (see link below)

How can the roots be once complex and again real?

Can someone please explain the dilemma??

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E3%2Bx%5E2%28-9%29%2Bx%2818%29-4%3D0

Comment: Some computations in complex numbers deliver real numbers...

Comment: I am not sure how one would introduce (in a relevant manner) non-real numbers  when computing roots of a real coefficient polynomial only having real roots also. @dan_fulea

Comment: Wolfram alpha did not interpret your second input properly. It got confused over your use of brackets and your omission of a multiplication sign.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Cardano's_formula - and look there for the case when the roots are real. The formula is valid in general, it is the one used by W-alpha.

Comment: @dan_fulea : That is true, but look at the WA formula how it contains `x(18)` etc. It is not interpreting the polynomial as intended, instead finding some unknown function `x(s)` evaluated at `s=18` to give a constant with unknown value.

Comment: ... oh, yes, i typed only `x^3 - 9x^2 + 18x - 4 = 0` in w-alpha, and i saw the roots without following the link... well, the problem was indeed with that `x(18)`, and so the solution is not really a complex number... `x^3 + x^2(-9) + x*(18) - 4 = 0` works, too. It is a strange idea of wolfram alpha to consider `x(18)` as a parameter... In the comments i was blindly suspecting the page delivers the stuff it delivers after `Roots[ x^3 - 9x^2 + 18x - 4 == 0 , x]`

Comment: Did you try wolfram alpha before asking the question this time? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a matter of notation in wolfram alpha. Try adding `*`:

`x^3+x^2*(-9)+x*(18)-4=0`.

You will see that now the roots match.

Comment: Alternately, just type out the polynomial the way you usually would: `x^3-9x^2+18x-4=0`. Give that to WA, and you get the right roots as well.

Comment: oh okay, i see it now

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The solutions are indeed real numbers. In your wolfram alpha solution for characteristic polynomial, notice that $x$ appears on the right hand side as well.